# Dockerizing a MongoDB and Express REST API not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

I am trying to Dockerize my API which uses Expressjs and MongoDB. When I run `docker-compose up`, MongoDB throws an error

```
fullstack-products-api | MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
fullstack-products-api |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:845:32)
fullstack-products-api |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:348:10
fullstack-products-api |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
fullstack-products-api |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
fullstack-products-api |     at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
fullstack-products-api |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1152:10)
fullstack-products-api |     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:347:20)
fullstack-products-api |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/server.ts:21:3)
fullstack-products-api |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
fullstack-products-api |     at Module.m._compile (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:23)
fullstack-products-api |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
fullstack-products-api |     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
fullstack-products-api |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
fullstack-products-api |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
fullstack-products-api |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
fullstack-products-api |     at main (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:198:14) {
fullstack-products-api |   reason: TopologyDescription {
fullstack-products-api |     type: 'Single',
fullstack-products-api |     setName: null,
fullstack-products-api |     maxSetVersion: null,
fullstack-products-api |     maxElectionId: null,
fullstack-products-api |     servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
fullstack-products-api |     stale: false,
fullstack-products-api |     compatible: true,
fullstack-products-api |     compatibilityError: null,
fullstack-products-api |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
fullstack-products-api |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
fullstack-products-api |     localThresholdMS: 15,
fullstack-products-api |     commonWireVersion: null
fullstack-products-api |   }
fullstack-products-api | }
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: fullstack-products-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Connection string

```js
const db: string = "mongodb://mongo:27017/products";
```

Where I connect

```js
mongoose
    .connect(db, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to database..."))
    .catch((err: Error) => console.log(err));
```

Whenever I look up the error, the solution is to change my Mongo connection string but I have followed that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the connection string? It looks like it is still trying to connect to the local host.

Comment: I added my connection string, it is mongodb://mongo:27017/products

Comment: Yes but look at the error : fullstack-products-api | MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 -> still localhost

Comment: That is my question, how do I fix that? You can see my connection string right there, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your connection code, if you can.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230763/discussion-between-samarmohan-and-rani-sharim).